# Unwanted Padding Under Action Bar

Tags: android

So I'm using this library [BottomBar](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar) to display a toolbar sort of view at the top my app. There's a strange padding that's showing up between the action bar and the bottom bar as shown in this picture (ignore the floating action button):
[image: Screenshot].

Here's my layout xml file:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent">
<com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
    android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    app:bb_behavior="shifting"
    app:bb_activeTabColor="#000000"
    app:bb_inActiveTabColor="#FFFFFF"
    app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottom_bar" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/movie_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_margin="18dp"
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:src="@drawable/create"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:backgroundTint="#A52A2A"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:elevation="8dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/movie_recycler_view"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
```

I've tried setting action bar padding to 0dp, bottom par padding 0dp, disabling actionbar shadow, etc., to no avail. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I've figured out the solution. It was the libraries fault....

Basically, the library required a special parameter: `app:bb_showShadow="false"` to disable the shadow.